# Selecting element (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

*I am working on migrating to Polymer 1.0*

Here is my template:

```
<template>
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="content">
            <content></content>
        </div>
        <div class="bar barY"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The content gets filled with text in the main html file.

I need to get the scroll height of this div.  I used to do:

```
height = $(this.shadowRoot).find('.content')[0].scrollHeight;
```

But this isn't working anymore:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined
```

I tried adding an id to the div, and selecting it like so:

```
height = this.$.content.scrollHeight;
```

But this is giving me a value of 0, even though there is lots of text in the content.

I am calling this code from the `ready` function.

Am I selecting the element correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<content>` does not actually contain the component's contents, rather it provides an *insertion point* for those contents, which will be siblings to the `<content>` element.  To get the elements which are inserted for a given `<content>` node, you can use the following:

```
var content = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('content');
var distributed = Polymer.dom(content).getDistributedNodes()
```

Documentation for the above can be found at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api-examples along with a more complete example.

Comment: Awesome thanks that did the trick.  Now I am having some trouble on the syntax of selecting a property, but I will ask that in a separate question.